# In Java Why can't I get 9 characters from decimal numbers over 255? Is it the sign bit?

Tags: java

This is for the headstails java homework assignment that you can find a few places online (like http://www.javaproblems.com/2013/01/medium-problem-tricky-heads-and-tails.html)

The idea is to input a decimal 0 to 511 and have it output a 3 x 3 matrix of H or T for 0 or 1's (mine works 0 to 255)

Here's my attempt though, that I couldn't get working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 511: ");
    //int num = keyboard.nextInt();
    int num = 458;
    String binNum = "";
    int temp;
    String[][] coinArr = new String[3][3]; // = [][];

    while(num > 0)
    {
        temp = (int) (num % 2);
        binNum = binNum + "" + temp;
        num = (int) (num / 2);
    }

    System.out.println("binNum length is " + binNum.length());
    System.out.println("binNum is " + binNum);

    binNum = String.format((binNum.length() < 9 ? ("%0"+ (9 - binNum.length())+"d%s") : "%0$d%s"), 0 ,binNum);
    System.out.println("binNum length is " + binNum.length());
    System.out.println("binNum is " + binNum);

    int k=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            binNum = binNum.replaceAll("0", "H");
            binNum = binNum.replaceAll("1", "T");
            coinArr[i][j] = binNum.substring(k, k+1);
            k++;
            System.out.print(coinArr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion from decimal to binary is wrong, the correct one is :

```
while(num > 0)
{
    temp = (int) (num % 2);
    binNum = temp + "" + binNum;
    num = (int) (num / 2);
}
```

Then you only need 9 characters in your binNum :

```
binNum = binNum.length() < 9 ? String.format("%0"+ (9 - binNum.length())+"d%s", 0 ,binNum) : binNum;

// You don't need this inside your loop
binNum = binNum.replaceAll("0", "H");
binNum = binNum.replaceAll("1", "T");

int k=0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        coinArr[i][j] = String.valueOf(binNum.charAt(k));
        k++;
        System.out.print(coinArr[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:-

1) Change

`binNum = binNum + "" + temp;`

to

`binNum = temp + binNum;`

2) Change

```
binNum = String.format((binNum.length() < 9 ? ("%0"+ (9 - binNum.length())+"d%s") : "%0$d%s"), 0 ,binNum);
```

to

```
binNum = String.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(binNum));
```